# How to make a google apps script that takes a random value from a column when out separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm sorry for the question, but I am not really a software developer and not familiar with java.  I've been struggling with this problem for days, and the deadline is reaching… so I hope to find some help.  Already really appreciated!!

What I am looking for is:
I have a Google Form that is linked to a Google Spreadsheet.  So every answer of the google form goes to that spreadsheet.  These answers are used in a google apps script to create a google doc file (based on the answers of the form).

Now in that Google Form, there are some Yes/No questions.  When they choose ‘Yes’ on the FIRST question, the idea is that the google apps script takes a random cell of the FIRST column of a (separate) ‘answer’ sheet.

When they choose ‘Yes’ on the SECOND question, the idea is that the google apps script takes a random cell of the SECOND column of the ‘answer’ sheet.   And so on.

When they choose ‘No’ on a question, nothing needs to happen.

Later on, these random chosen answers/cells also needs to be placed in the google sheet. (like the Name and Email)

I’ll show what I have for now:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Name = e.values[1];
  var Email1 = e.values[2];
  var OpenQuestion = e.values[3];
  var YesNoQuestion1 = e.values[4];
  var YesNoQuestion2 = e.values[5];
  var YesNoQuestion3 = e.values[6];

var TemplateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Unique-folder-ID");
var copy = TemplateFile.makeCopy(Name, TemplateResponseFolder);

var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();

// replace the value between {{xyz}} by the variable in the google doc.
body.replaceText("{{Name}}", Name);
body.replaceText("{{AchterNaam}}", LastName);
body.replaceText("{{email1}}", Email1);
body.replaceText("{{OpenQuestion}}", OpenQuestion);
body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion1}}", YesNoQuestion1);
body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion2}}", YesNoQuestion2);
body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion3}}", YesNoQuestion3);

  doc.saveAndClose();
}
// the script above works fine.
```

But I really have no idea how to make the ‘random lookup function’ work and store that value as a variable to use it in a google doc.
I’ve been trying with:

```
function selectRandomCell(searchColumn,resultCellRow,resultCellColumn) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Unique-ID-of-the-answer-sheet");
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var values = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i][0] == "") {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      values.push(range[i][0]);
    }
  }

  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]);
}
```

Please help me.  (And sorry for my English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Name = e.values[1];
  var Email1 = e.values[2];
  var OpenQuestion = e.values[3];
  var YesNoQuestion1 = (e.values[4] === `Yes`) ? selectRandomCell(1) : `No`;
  var YesNoQuestion2 = (e.values[5] === `Yes`) ? selectRandomCell(2) : `No`;
  var YesNoQuestion3 = (e.values[6] === `Yes`) ? selectRandomCell(3) : `No`;

  var TemplateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Unique-folder-ID");
  var copy = TemplateFile.makeCopy(Name, TemplateResponseFolder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // replace the value between {{xyz}} by the variable in the google doc.
  body.replaceText("{{Name}}", Name);
  body.replaceText("{{AchterNaam}}", LastName);
  body.replaceText("{{email1}}", Email1);
  body.replaceText("{{OpenQuestion}}", OpenQuestion);
  body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion1}}", YesNoQuestion1);
  body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion2}}", YesNoQuestion2);
  body.replaceText("{{YesNoQuestion3}}", YesNoQuestion3);

    doc.saveAndClose();
}

function selectRandomCell(targetColumn) {
  const answerSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`NAME_OF_YOUR_ANSWER_SHEET`);
  const values = answerSheet.getRange(2, targetColumn, answerSheet.getLastRow()-1)
                            .getDisplayValues()
                            .flat()
                            .filter(String);

  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}
```

- The first change is determining what the Yes/No responses are.

We accomplish this as `(e.values[4] === 'Yes') ? selectRandomCell(1) : 'No'` which translates to `(is this value 'Yes'?) If so, get a random cell from column 1. If not, leave it as 'No'`.

- The second change is simplifying the `selectRandomCell` function.

Based on which column number you enter, the function will take all values of that column and select one at random, and return it back for us. If this function is 'called' in our `YesNoQuestion` variable, the result of this function becomes the value of that variable.

### What You Need To Do:

- Create or update the sheet that you would like the 'Yes' answers to be selected from. The name of this sheet should be in this Spreadsheet and the name of the sheet must replace `NAME_OF_YOUR_ANSWER_SHEET` in the `selectRandomCell()` function.
- If you are not going to use Columns A, B, C (1, 2, 3), update the numbers being 'passed' to in the `selectRandomCell()` function of the `YesNoQuestion` variables to match the corresponding column(s). Please also note, the `selectRandomCell` function is also expecting the first row to be selectable values.

**If you get any errors, or need further explanation, just let me know!**

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help!!
It’s (almost) perfect!   It would be great if the random search in the column would start from row 2 (in the answer sheet).  This way I can use row 1 for the description of that column (example: ‘answers question about xxxx’).  Then it would be really PERFECT! ;-)

Comment: @GunterKlaasen Updated! Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks again for your update!  This also seems to work, but when I was testing, I’ve noticed that this function also includes empty cells because sometimes the return value was empty (this can happen when the answer to the Yes/No question is No, but this happened also when the answer to the Yes/No question was Yes).  Is this something you can fix?  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @GunterKlaasen Sorry about that! Error should be fixed, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You are my HERO!!!  If I could, I would hug and almost kiss you!  ;-)  Thank you SOOO much!!!  It works perfect!!!    (just a detail and minor update, but for the people who want to copy the script:  place a   ;  at the end of the lines of the ‘const’ variables “anwserSheet” and “values”)

Comment: Semicolons added and hug received! Would you mind marking this answer as accepted? Let me know if you need any other help! Best wishes